# Open apk as new android studio projecy

Tags: android, apk

I've lost the project folder for my app. But I have the apk. Is there any way to carry on my Work with the apk. I have tried to use apk annalise.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

There are tools that can decompile APKs, such as [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) and https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar.

And also [jd-gui](http://jd.benow.ca/).

But non of them will recreate your project.

If you lost a lot of code and don't have a backup, these might help, but you will still need to put in manual labor to create a project and properly arrange the resulting files in it.

Also, a lot of Java code will need fixing.

If your project is small, you might as well start from scratch, and try to keep a backup next time!

You might also want to consider using a file recovery program instead.